# Translation needed for "school board"

Tags: traducción

Is there a Spanish word for school board? If so, what would the translation be?

Comment: Could you indicate please if you need the translation for a specific country? It can vary according to each Law on Education.

Comment: Moreover, I think it's a better idea to ask the translations in different questions.

Comment: The translation I want is for Spanish being read in the United States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Consejo escolar", "junta escolar" or "comité escolar" would be the most neutral for any Spanish speaker, anybody would understand the same.

As for US, the translation they use in the [Los Angeles High School](http://www.lahigh.org/apps/pages/index.jsp?uREC_ID=165347&type=d) is "consejo escolar".

Comment: I like your answer. All the three terms you provide are perfectly inteligible everywhere, whatever you are used to in your country.

Answer (score 1):

It's "consejo escolar" in Spain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an alternative translation could be: "junta escolar"

Answer (score 0):

I think this probably varies regionally, but here in Argentina a school board would be a "junta coordinadora", generally called simply "coordinadora".

"Junta" translates as "board"; the chairman of a "junta" is usually called "secretario". Not sure about schools, though.